# ASP.NET :HyperLinkColumn - 'HyperLinkColumn' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error:
Element 'HyperLinkColumn' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site.

Within my GridView before I had:

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProID" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#0066cc" 
     HeaderStyle-Font-Size="7pt" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" 
     HeaderText="ProID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" />
```

I replaced that with:

```
     <asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="ProID" 
      DataNavigateUrlFormatString="pro.aspx?pro={0}" 
      DataTextField="ProID" HeaderText="ProID" SortExpression="ProID">
      <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
      </asp:HyperLinkColumn>
```

Not sure why it is giving me this message. My goal is simply to make that column into a hyplink so that I can have the user to to the designated page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: You can use HyperLinkField:

```
  <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ProID"
   DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://www.google.com/id={0}" DataTextField="ProID"
   HeaderText="ProID" />
```

2: You can use navigateUrl:

```
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="btnGo" Text='<%# Eval("ProID") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "pro.aspx?pro" + Eval("ProID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```